# Go http server in docker returns empty reply

Tags: docker, http, go

I just follow the docker docs example [this](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/develop/), I have these lines in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.18-buster AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY *.go ./
RUN go build -o /docker-gs-ping-roach

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /docker-gs-ping-roach /docker-gs-ping-roach
EXPOSE 4433
USER nonroot:nonroot
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-gs-ping-roach"]
```

In `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  docker-gs-ping-roach:
    depends_on:
      - roach
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: rest-server
    hostname: rest-server
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 4433:4433
    environment:
      - PGUSER=${PGUSER:-totoro}
      - PGPASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD:?database password not set}
      - PGHOST=${PGHOST:-db}
      - PGPORT=${PGPORT:-26257}
      - PGDATABASE=${PGDATABASE:-mydb}
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
  roach:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:latest-v20.1
    container_name: roach
    hostname: db
    networks:
      - mynet
    ports:
      - 26257:26257
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - roach:/cockroach/cockroach-data
    command: start-single-node --insecure

volumes:
  roach:

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

There is no error shown in the terminal and the database is working on http://localhost:8080/ but when I visit the go app on http://localhost:4433 i got this error

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

I checked the containers to make sure that I hit the right port:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your `main.go`?  What routes **should** be accessible and non-empty? If you run your go program outside of docker, what does curl return?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is the same code of this repo https://github.com/olliefr/docker-gs-ping-roach

Comment: Why do you think port 4443 (or 8000) is correct? https://github.com/olliefr/docker-gs-ping-roach/blob/main/main.go#L42-L45

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got port 4433 or 8000 from.

[The docs](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/develop/) show `-p 80:8080`, so change your ports to use that instead.

More specifically, the web-server for the Go app defaults to [start on port 8080](https://github.com/olliefr/docker-gs-ping-roach/blob/main/main.go#L42-L45), but that conflicts with CockroachDB, so you need to change it on the host.

Or you need to define `HTTP_PORT=4433`, then the port mapping of `4433:4433` would work.

Comment: I have something else on localhost (80) so I change it to 4433

Comment: Okay. Like I said, add a new environment variable